# Convert Monday, 28th May 2022 to a data object in date-fns

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, date-fns

In date-fns, `_.format(new Date(), 'EEEE, do LLL R')` gives me `Thursday, 12th May 2022`, now how can I convert the date string to a date object in date-fns? I tried `_.parse('Thursday, 12th May 2022', 'EEEE, do LLL R', new Date())`, it tells me

```
> Uncaught RangeError: The format string mustn't contain `do` and `R` at the same time
```

Thanks

Comment: This is expected per the [compatibility table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQOPU3xUhplll6dyoMmVUXHKl_8CRDs6_ueLmex3SoqwhuolkuN3O05l4rqx5h1dKX8eb46Ul-CCSrq/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true)

Comment: just use `y` instead of `R`